# How can I make the mouse smoothly transition to a new relative position within a given timeframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, mouseevent, ctypes

So once the If statement is true, I want the program to make the mouse move 29 pixels down smoothly within a 1 second time frame rather than instantly.

```
from ctypes import *
import time

u32 = windll.user32

while True:
    if u32.GetKeyState(0x01) not in [0, 1] and u32.GetKeyState(0x02) not in [0,1] and u32.GetKeyState(0x11) not in [0, 1] and u32.GetKeyState(0x14) == 1:
        #If Right click, Left click, and CTRL are pressed, and CAPS LOCK is on
        u32.mouse_event(0x0001, 0, 29)
        #Mouse is moved 29 pixels down
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate through each pixel and set a wait timer per....

```
from ctypes import *
import time

u32 = windll.user32

while True:
    if u32.GetKeyState(0x01) not in [0, 1] and u32.GetKeyState(0x02) not in [0,1] and u32.GetKeyState(0x11) not in [0, 1] and u32.GetKeyState(0x14) == 1:
        #If Right click, Left click, and CTRL are pressed, and CAPS LOCK is on
        for i in range(29):
           u32.mouse_event(0x0001, 0, 1)
           time.sleep(.01)
        #Mouse is moved 29 pixels down
        #break
```

Comment: Smoothly over 1 second would be `time.sleep(1/29)`, assuming `time.sleep` accurately sleeps for exactly that time (a wrong assumption ).  A spinwait would be more accurate.